# How to undo git folder I created because of mistake?

Tags: git, git-init

I was recently learning the git and windows PowerShell functions. I mistakenly made my Admin folder git repository and it is continuously showing changes I have made since then. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the .git directory should do the trick

Comment: I just did that but it doesn't change anything. I am practicing in vs code it keeps showing in the source control that I made 5k changes.

Comment: Also search for `.git` folders at upper levels, if you're unsure you might have unwittingly created some earlier.